# How to passing message using message queue in C?

Tags: c, process, message-queue, fifo

I try to write my program in C with FIFO process communications.
I have two child process, Scanner and Analyzer.
The process who name is Scanner does scan of dir and send the name content dir  to process Analyzer. The process Analyzer should be print the files names. The problem is that the process Analyzer doesn't print the all name. Why ?

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#define MAX_DIM 2048

typedef struct
{
    char eof;
    long mtype; // 0 Analyzer 
    long count;
    char mtext[MAX_DIM];
} msg;

void child_scanner(const char *directory, int coda)
{

    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *entry;
    msg messaggio;          // struct dove salvare le informazioni
    struct stat statBuffer; // buffer su dove scrivere le informazioni

    // apro la directory
    if ((dp = opendir(directory)) == NULL)
    {
        perror(directory);
        exit(1);
    }

    // cambia la directory corrente
    if (chdir(directory) == -1)
    {
        perror(directory);
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {
        // prendo le informazioni
        lstat(entry->d_name, &statBuffer);
        if (S_ISREG(statBuffer.st_mode))
        {
            strcpy(messaggio.mtext, entry->d_name);
            messaggio.mtype = 0;   
            messaggio.eof = 0;
            messaggio.count = 0;
            if (msgsnd(coda, &messaggio, sizeof(char) + strlen(messaggio.mtext) + 1, 0) == -1)
            {
                perror("msgsnd");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("Scanner: %s\n", messaggio.mtext); // stampa il nome del file
        }
    }

    strcpy(messaggio.mtext, "quit\n");
    messaggio.eof = 1;
    messaggio.mtype = 0;
    messaggio.count=0;
    if (msgsnd(coda, &messaggio, sizeof(char) + strlen(messaggio.mtext) + 1, 0) == -1)
    {
        perror("msgsnd");
        exit(1);
    }

    closedir(dp);
    exit(0);
}

void child_analyzer(int coda)
{
    printf("\n");
    msg messaggio;

    do
    {
        if (msgrcv(coda, &messaggio, sizeof(messaggio) - sizeof(long), 0, 0) == -1)
        {
            perror("msgrcv");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Analyzer: %s\n", messaggio.mtext);

    } while (messaggio.eof != 1);

    exit(0);
}



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */

    int ds_coda;            // coda
    struct stat statBuffer; // buffer di tipo struct stat su cui scrivere le informazioni

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "uso: %s <directory>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((ds_coda = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, IPC_CREAT | 0600)) == -1)
    {
        perror("coda msgget");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (((stat(argv[1], &statBuffer)) == -1 || (!S_ISDIR(statBuffer.st_mode))))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Problema con parametro: '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        // Figlio Scanner
        child_scanner(argv[1], ds_coda);
    }
    else if (fork() == 0)
    {
        sleep(1);
        child_analyzer(ds_coda);
    }
    
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);

    msgctl(ds_coda, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

this is my input :

```
./alpha-usage /Users/valentinofabrisvalenti/Desktop/Sistemi\ Operativi\ \(Laboratorio\)/Esami/Code/12-02-2016
```

and this is my output:

```
Scanner: palindrome-filter.c
Scanner: dictionary.txt
Scanner: palindrome-filter
Scanner: compito_2016-02-12 (1).pdf

Analyzer: palin
Analyzer: palin
Analyzer: palin
Analyzer: compito_2016
Analyzer: compito_2016
```

Please help me to understand, thank you.

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated languages

Answer (score 0):

1. You should check the length returned by msgrcv().  I think you will find that it is less than you expect.
2. You should check the length you are passing to msgsnd().  I think you will find it is less than you need, because you're missing two `sizeof(long)`s there (for `mtype` and `count`).